502 Bad Gateway Error Message on MLFlow Server on EC2 with S3 Backend
For all practical purposes, my MLFlow Server appears to be functioning as expected. I dont see any issue with accessing the server, or any of the artifacts within experiments.
However, I occasionally see an error message pop up, usually on the Experiments page. I am unsure what is causing this error message to pop up especially when I can clearly see my experiments listed and can navigate them just fine. However, I would like to diagnose and fix the issue that is persisting.
502 Bad Gateway
502 Bad Gateway 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.24.0
This error pops up as in the image attached above, when navigating the website (on to the experiments tab as best as I can see).
In the network tab, I can see the following corresponding error:
Request URL: https://my.subdomain.com/ajax-api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get?experiment_id=0
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway
Remote Address: ec2.public.ip.address:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Im not sure if it is related but I also see:
[useFetchExperimentRuns] Invalid hook usage: useFetchExperimentRuns is not supported anymore when shareExperimentViewByTags flag is enabled.

In the Console Log.
Any help in diagnosing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Expecting to not see any 502 Bad Gateway Errors. Not sure where to start with this problem.
